# Ubuntu 16.04: How to map ESC and left CTRL to CAPS and CAPS to ESC for Vim

Tags: ubuntu, vim, keyboard-shortcuts, ubuntu-16.04

I am using `Vim 8` in `Ubuntu 16.04` and want to remap some keys.

1. I want to remap `left CTRL` to `CAPS LOCK` when held with another key. The original `left CTRL` key can still work the same as before.
2. Also, I want to remap `ESC` to `CAPS LOCK` when pressed individually. So it is shared with the remapped `left CTRL`.
3. Lastly, I want to map `CAPS LOCK` to `ESC`.

How do I achieve all 3 either by means inside Vim or through external downloads as long as the key pressing doesn't lag? I don't mind if these settings apply outside Vim.

I know this is a popular setup and found many similar questions online including this site. But they weren't the exact setup I'm looking for or were outdated and doesn't seem to work for me.

I have tried https://github.com/alols/xcape but maybe didn't get it working properly. I have heard about `xmodmap` but I don't think it can do everything I asked for.

Comment: None of that can be achieved in Vim.

Comment: I'm fine if it is achieved through something external to vim.